# ansible package vs yum module

Tags: ansible

I am a newbie in Ansible world. I have already created some playbook and I am getting more and more familiar with this technology by the day. 
In my playbooks I have always used the command `yum` to install and manage new packages, but recently I found out about an another command `package` that claims to be OS independent.

Thus my question: What is the difference between them?

In particular, if I create a role and a playbook that I know that will be executed in RHEL environment (where yum is the default package manager), which advantage do I get from using the command `package` rather than `yum`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ansible `package` module autodetect your OS default package manager (e.g yum, apt) from existing facts.

The fact environment variable which stores is `"ansible_pkg_mgr"`.

Here is a command for same.
`ansible localhost -m setup | grep ansible_pkg_mgr`.

If you are using multiple OS in your environment, then instead of specifying package manager you should use `package` over `yum or apt`.

Comment: is there any downside to `package` over a specific module (`apt`, `yum`, ...), or, in other words, "should you go for `yum`/`dnf`/`apt` if you are **not** in a multi-OS environment? If so, why exactly @deepak ?

Answer (score 10):

Ansible package module is more general **but looks like you still have to handle differences in package names**. From [package module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/package_module.html)

```
# This uses a variable as this changes per distribution.
- name: remove the apache package
  package:
    name: "{{ apache }}"
    state: absent
```

In this case package name for:

- RHEL - httpd
- Debian/Ubuntu - apache2

so `{{ apache }}` variable must be set according to the OS.

Comment: In addition differences are not only in package names but also in the parameters the OS-specific module accepts (and which are passed from `package` to e.g. `apt` and/or `dnf`).